# I have deployed a Asp.net application, it must check the local system ie: client system drive has a folder(eg: Test) or not.

Tags: c#, .net

I have deployed a Asp.net application, it must check the local system ie: client system drive has a folder(eg: Test) or not. I tried but code checking only the server not the client system.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far for better understanding?

Comment: A server can't look at the file system of a client. That would be a huge security concern and just isn't possible. If you could explain some of the reasons you want this functionality in your question, we may be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: If the folder does not exist then the application will create the folder and save the file

Comment: string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/folder/file.txt";
      string dipath = @"C:/BigdBiz/";

   string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(dipath); 

foreach (string dir in dirs)
{
   Label1.Text = Label1.Text + dir;
 }

  try
  {
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dipath);
   DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
    FileInfo[] TxtFiles = di.GetFiles("*.TXT";
   string ff = di.Name;
   Label1.Text = "OK";
    }
   catch
    {
     Label1.Text = "Catch Error";
    }

Comment: Sorry I dont know to post my reply.... The above code is what I have tried

Comment: Edit your question and you can insert code just put a bold UPDATE title under your original question and then you can add code there. However, the code you posted will only check server side by design. There is no way for the server to automatically find files and upload them. Your web app must use Forms, JavaScript, or plugins to upload files and it must be initiated from the client. There are plenty of "Upload Files in ASP.NET" examples here.